# How do I remove multiple href links via the ID with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues removing several of my href links that all have the same ID.  Here is my code snippet:

```
    $('.delblk').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);

        $.getJSON("../ajax_blocked.php?op=delete&id="+id, function(data) {
        if (data) {

            $("#delblk_"+id).each(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="sent.php" id="delblk_7" class="delblk" ><span class="label label-important">Unblock</span></a>
<a href="sent.php" id="delblk_7" class="delblk" ><span class="label label-important">Unblock</span></a>
<a href="sent.php" id="delblk_8" class="delblk" ><span class="label label-important">Unblock</span></a>
```

It's only removing the first href link and not both of them.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

The problem is that a id must be unique in your document, use the `class` attribute instead.

So you cant use the `id (#)` selector.

But you can use the `Attribute Equals Selector` to iterate through your elements, check my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/VNXpU/)

> w3c The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

#### Sample

```
$("a[id='delblk_"+id+"']").each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [w3c - ID Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)
- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/VNXpU/)

Comment: I swapped the class and ID and everything is working...thanks!

Comment: You got a mistake in the selector. `$("a[id='delblk_'+id]")` => `$("a[id=delblk_"+id+"]")`

Answer (score 2):

You can **never ever** have multiple elements with the same id, use `class` instead of `id`

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

**[docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)**

Do you have the same `id` like you brother, father or everyone else in your country?
Each HTML page is like a country, and id is  ummm like id... must be **unique**.

Comment: Thanks, If I change my class to include the ID how can I trigger a click event with every class name being unique and not knowing the ID portion of the class?

Comment: @Paul. What exactly is the current problem?

Comment: @Paul you can select a class like this $('.class_name').do(your(stuff){here})